# unable to add a variable as parameter in url with django

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-templates

I'm using django ver. 2.0.3, with python 3.6 and following models

```
@python_2_unicode_compatible
class ArticleDb(models.Model):

    slug = models.SlugField(primary_key=True, unique=True, blank=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, validators=[MinLengthValidator(5)])
    content = models.TextField(max_length=5000)
```

then I have following template

```
{% for article in articles %}

                <tr>
                    <td>{{ article.title }}</td>   
                    <td><a href="{% url 'view_article' slug_addr= article.slug %}">{{ article.slug }}</a></td>
                </tr>

{% endfor %}
```

the url.py is following

```
...
path('code/<slug:slug_addr>/', views.ViewArticle.as_view(), name="view_article"),
...
```

so the problem is **slug_addr=** if I assign a string value it works but if I put template variables like article.slug don't works, althought {{article.slug}} works, every time I get this error:

```
Reverse for 'view_article' with keyword arguments '{'slug_addr': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['code\\/(?P<slug_addr>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)\\/$']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{% for article in articles %}
     <tr>
       <td>{{ article.title }}</td>   
       <td><a href="{% url 'view_article' article.slug %}">{{ article.slug }}</a></td>
     /tr> 
{% endfor %}
```

you dont have to pass the name as you have only one parameter in the url.

Comment: same error: Reverse for 'view_article' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['code\\/(?P<slug_addr>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)\\/$']